# Multiple Airflow setups on the same GKE cluster

Tags: airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer, dbt

We are currently looking at setting up multiple Airflow stacks on the same GKE cluster but in  different namespaces (to save on costs) to run DBT jobs.

Each Airflow stack within its namespace would use RBAC authentication to auth end users to run or observe jobs.

I understand this isn't a typical use case but the other alternative would be to have a separate Cloud Composer for each service line which would be quite costly.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple Airflow DAGs on the same GKE cluster by using KubernetesPodOperator in the way given here [1](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator#affinity-config). Affinity is used to constrain which nodes your pod is eligible to be scheduled on, based on labels. The code is inside affinity{...} in the same link. Also, it is mentioned that you can use a custom namespace.